# Adding annotations with Java Annotation Processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I know that the Annotation Processor is normally used to *consume* annotations and react to them. I, however, have a use case where this "reaction" involves adding other annotations. Can this be done within the processor itself? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **yes**, and you don't have anything specific to do.

An annotation processor is used to create **new** source files, not to modify existing ones. So when you say "adding other annotations", I guess you mean "creating new classes that hold annotations".

Annotation processing is done in rounds. At each round, the [process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#process%28java.util.Set,%20javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment%29) method of your annotation processor is called.

If a processor generate new source files, another round of annotation processing starts

- newly generated source files are parsed and annotations are processed as before
- processors invoked on previous rounds are also invoked on all subsequent rounds

So basically : you have nothing to do, it already works ;-) .

Comment: Thanks so far but actually I was hoping that there would be a way to alter the existing source files, adding new annotations there. Is that possible as well?

Comment: No, not with annotation processing. Annotation Processing can only be used to create new files.

Comment: However, you could modify the bytecode to add annotations (see ASM for instance), or add those annotations through reflection at runtime (see [AnnotationInjector](http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/02/20/Introducing-AnnotationInjector))